# Getting "Please install an operating system" after installing Ubuntu on HP laptop

Tags: 16.04, hp

Just got a new a new HP laptop without an OS installed on it.

I installed Ubuntu from a USB.
The installation completed successfully.
Then it asked me to restart.

After restart, I get message saying `Please install an operating system`.

I can also reach a terminal with prompt saying `grub>`, don't know if it helps.

Turns out I can press <kbd>Esc</kbd> to get to boot menu. Then tell the laptop to boot from EFI file called `grunb` under a folder named `ubuntu`.

Then Ubuntu loads...
However, if I restart the laptop, I need to do the process again...

Still searching for an automatic solution.

How can I make this work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Find out which EFI file path you need

- go to boot options
- select install from EFI file -  ** REMEMBER THE PATH
- see ubuntu loads

This is not the end as you need to define this as the default method

- go to boot menu (for me it was pressing `esc` on splash screen)
- go to `boot setup ==> advanced ==> boot setup`
- add a custom boot method

  - type in the EFI file
- go back to the setup menu
- go to EFI boot sequence
- make `custom` the first step
- I also unchecked other boot options except for USB and custom but not sure if it is required

This should make ubuntu load by default.

Answer (score 1):

Just hit the "reset bios settings to default" option.
It worked for me, nothing else did.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://askubuntu.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://askubuntu.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1323258)